# Why do we use performWait in core data?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, semaphore

As we know that

- performWait function synchronously performs a given block on the context’s queue.
- perform function asynchronously performs a given block on the context’s queue.

In my project, I used the performWait function to fetch the data because I want the calling thread to wait until the block has executed before returning. It is the easiest way to implement it. But then I realized that the performWait works very slow. Then I tried to implement own synchronization with a semaphore and using the perform function. Here are the results:

**PerformWait**

```
    let currentTime1 = getCurrentMillis()
    context?.performAndWait({
        ....
    })
    let currentTime2 = getCurrentMillis()
    let diff = currentTime2 - currentTime1
    print("getActivities diff: " + String(diff))
```

**Perform and a semaphore**

```
    let currentTime1 = getCurrentMillis()
    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
    context?.perform({
       ....
       semaphore.signal()
    })
    semaphore.wait()
    let currentTime2 = getCurrentMillis()
    let diff = currentTime2 - currentTime1
    print("getActivities diff: " + String(diff))
```

getActivities diff: 1248 ms

getActivitiesWithSemaphore diff: 90 ms

OK, I know that it is easier. But, why is it so slow? what are the other advantages of using it against the perform function?

Comment: Is the time difference consistent if you try it multiple times? What if you reverse the order of the tests? It's possible that the Core Data row cache is making the second test faster.

Comment: I tried again and again. The second solution is always faster.

Comment: I don't know of any reason it would be. If you can post your full test code I'd love to take a look.

Comment: What is happening at '...', also you can use instruments to profile this and see where the time is spent.

Comment: ...  fetching operation is "let fetchedEntities = try self.context?.fetch(fetchRequest)"  . I think IOS also use the same synchronization method. But it does something extra. I do not know what is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The `perform(_:)` method treats the block you have submitted as a user event, which means that at the end of every perform block it will make sure that all changes are processed and relevant notifications are sent.
>
> every block submitted through the `perform(_:)` method gets wrapped in an `autorelease` pool.

`performAndWait(_:)` has nasty side-effects and no autoreleasepool, it will block the calling thread completely! You have to call `processPendingChanges` or `save()` for changes to have effect.